# How to sort nested field in a Query?

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma

I am trying to get this Query to sort the `ideas` of `users`:

```
  users {
    id
    ideas(orderBy: createdAt_DESC) {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

It works without the `orderBy` argument.
However with the `orderBy` arg, I get this error: `"Unknown argument \"orderBy\" on field \"ideas\" of type \"User\"."`

My `ideas` schema is [here](https://github.com/hmmChase/next-graphql-starter/blob/master/backend/src/schema/schema.graphql#L29)

My `ideas` resolver is [here](https://github.com/hmmChase/next-graphql-starter/blob/master/backend/src/resolvers/ideaResolver.js#L16)

Btw, if I Query `ideas` with the `orderBy` directly:

```
query ideas {
  ideas(orderBy: createdAt_DESC) {
    id
  }
}
```

It works.
I am just confused how to make the nested field sorting work.

Comment: Ever figure out why it works this way?